# How to create two separate indices: Subject index and Index of Authors

Tags: bibtex, citing, indexing, subdividing

I am working on my thesis and I have to include in the text the Subject Index and Index of Authors. I'm using BibTeX (package `natbib`) and package `makeidx` for marking the terms for Subject index (I'm using MikTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter). Problem is that     `\citeindextrue` command from the `natbib` package  write the  citations into the `.idx` indexing file and I don't know how to separate both indices. I'd like to have first e.g. Subject Index (with that title) and than Index of Authors. Do you have any suggestions?

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\citeindextrue 

This is a  text with few references, e.g. \cite{Doreian05} or \Citet{Doreian05}.\\
key words: network\index{network}, blockmodeling\index{blockmodeling}, and so on.
% bibliography
\bibliographystyle{mcbride} 
% the file with bibliography entries blockmodeling.bib
\bibliography{bibliography}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The entry in the bibliography file (`bibliography.bib`) is e.g.

```
@BOOK{Doreian05,
author = {Patrick Doreian and Vladimir Batagelj and Anu\v{s}ka Ferligoj},
title = {Generalized Blockmodeling},
year = {2005},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
address = {New York, NY, USA}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should maybe have a look at `\usepackage{imakeidx}`

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex
    \makeindex[name=authors,title=Authors,columns=3]
\usepackage{natbib}  

\makeindex  
\begin{document}  
\citeindextrue   

This is a  text with few references, e.g. \cite{Doreian05} or \Citet{Doreian05}.\\
And it has fancy authors. \index[authors]{Doreian, Patrick} \index[authors]{Batagelj, Vladimir} \index[authors]{Ferligoj, Anu\v{s}ka}
key words: network\index{network}, blockmodeling\index{blockmodeling}, and so on.  
% bibliography  
\bibliographystyle{mcbride}   
% the file with bibliography entries blockmodeling.bib  
\bibliography{bibliography}
\printindex[authors]
\printindex  
\end{document}
```

hopefully it is helpful

Disclaimer: i've *not* tested this tex-code - just written down some ideas.

Comment: Thank you @epsilonhalbe, you are a genius! :)   First of all you answer was very quick and effective, and second, you are also a magician, because you added in the text three of the most cited authors from my dissertation.  I know that this is not the place for such questions but anyway: Are social networks and blockmodeling your research topics? Thank you again ;)

Comment: Nope those three authors are in the bibfile you attached - my field of research is mathematics ;-) glad to help you. And may i ask you - mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Ups, I was so glad to have a solutionthat I forget what I wrote in bibfile ;)

Answer (score 4):

there's a good entry in the [tex faq](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-multind) that shows several options.  if you have tex live installed, you can access this via `texdoc multind`.

unfortunately, it doesn't include imakeidx (suggested by @epsilonhalbe), a package which looks quite promising; i've notified the faq maintainer of the omission.

UPDATE: the faq has been updated to recognize additional packages for preparing multiple indexes; well worth visiting if you need this facility.